# Perl and Ruby Hash syntax

Tags: ruby, perl, hash

I am really new to Perl and after reading some code, I stumbled upon this statement:

```
my_hash{string}++
```

where the `my_hash` variable is a Hash, and the string is an arbitrary String.

My guess is:

```
my_hash{string} = string++
```

and can anyone translate this line of code into Ruby as well?

Comment: `string++` would be trying to increment the string, e.g. what do you think the value of `apple++` would be? `orange`? `applf`?

Comment: @MarcB It would be `applf` in Perl (assuming the operation is performed on a scalar). I believe `"apple" += 1` is not defined in Ruby but `"apple".succ` should also produce `applf`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot true, I edited my comment to state that it has to be performed on a scalar.

Comment: I think you mean `$my_hash{string}++` not `my_hash{string}++`, there is a missing `$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$var++;
```

means

```
$var = $var + 1;
```

but it's actually closer to

```
$var = defined($var) ? $var+1 : 1;
```

since the LHS is treated as zero (without warning) if it's undefined. Similarly,

```
$my_hash{key}++;
```

is equivalent to

```
$my_hash{key} = defined($my_hash{key}) ? $my_hash{key}+1 : 1;
```

(There are some other minor differences in rare corner cases, but nothing you care about.)

---

The Ruby equivalent is

```
my_hash["key"] = my_hash["key"].to_i + 1;
```

or

```
# If my_hash["key"] is a number,
# Or if "my_hash" was created using "my_hash = Hash.new(0)".
my_hash["key"] += 1;
```

---

```
$ perl -E'
   my %my_hash;
   $my_hash{key}++;  say $my_hash{key};
   $my_hash{key}++;  say $my_hash{key};
'
1
2

$ ruby -e'
   my_hash = {};
   my_hash["key"] = my_hash["key"].to_i + 1;  p my_hash["key"];
   my_hash["key"] = my_hash["key"].to_i + 1;  p my_hash["key"];
'
1
2

$ ruby -e'
   my_hash = {};
   my_hash["key"] = 0;
   my_hash["key"] += 1;  p my_hash["key"];
   my_hash["key"] += 1;  p my_hash["key"];
'
1
2

$ ruby -e'
   my_hash = Hash.new(0);
   my_hash["key"] += 1;  p my_hash["key"];
   my_hash["key"] += 1;  p my_hash["key"];
'
1
2
```

Comment: `my_hash["key"] = my_hash["key"].to_i + 1` is an alternative (`nil=to_i` is 0).

Comment: A cleaner approach to the `nil` behavior you replicate is `my_hash = Hash.new(0)`, which will default values to 0 the first time you reference their key.

Comment: @steenslag, Thanks! Incorporated.

Comment: @Kristján, Thanks! Incorporated.

Answer (score 1):

`my_hash{string}++` is incrementing an integer stored in the hash, eg:

```
my %my_hash;
$my_hash{hi} = 0;
$my_hash{hi}++;
print "$_ $my_hash{$_}\n" for (keys %my_hash);
#> hi 1
```

Ruby hashes are accessed with `[]`, and Ruby doesn't implement `++`, so you must use `+= 1`. The equivalent Ruby code is then:

```
my_hash = {}
my_hash['hi'] = 0
my_hash['hi'] += 1
puts my_hash
#> {"hi"=>1}
```

Comment: The hash value in Perl and Ruby need not be an integer. `++` and `+=1` work with floating point numbers, too.